# Click and onchange event with file input not working properly in ie

Tags: javascript, iframe, file-upload

I am having a file upload script that works fine in all major browser including ie, but when I hide the file input and place a button for it and try to upload it using iframe method where I call the click event for file input using javascript and thn after the user select a file I call the onchange event again using javascript to submit the form entries using iframe method...

I analyzed the script and find out that its causing this problem when I invoke the file input with a javascript click event other wise it works really fine for me...

Now I want to invoke the file input using button in IE...

The script is as follow:

```
<form><input type="file" name="file_url" id="file_url" onChange="fileUpload(this.form,'filename.php','div_id'); return false;" />

</form>
<img src="uploadbtn.png" onClick="callclick(); return false;" />
<div id="div_id"></div>
```